# Java: terminated, exit value: -1073740940

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am using 32-bit Eclipse Juno in Windows 7, and has set the 'JRE System Library' also as 32-bit 'JavaSE-1.7'. In the '**Window->Preferences->Java->InstalledJREs->Execution Environments**' part, in the '**Exexcution Environments**' section I selected '**JavaSE-1.7**' and on the right column, which is '**Compatible JREs:**', I ticked '**jdk7[perfect match]**' for it. But when running my application, after it run for a little bit, I got the following error:

```
terminated, exit value: -1073740940
```

When I select '**jdk1.7.0_15[perfect match]**' for '**Compatible JREs**' in the '**Window->Preferences**', this time I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\MyCodes\AdtLab\build\x86\vc11\bin\Adt.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.
```

This is the first time I see this kind of error. My other applications developed under the same environment were running well. What could be the reason for this? By the way, my OS is 64-bit Windows 7. If someone would suggest that I should install 64-bit Eclipse and JRE, then my question would be: why then my previous codes are running well in this environment? Thanks.

Comment: "...why then my previous codes are running well in this environment?...." Do you mean your old code works and new code is not working ?? If I were you I would stick with all 64 bits.

Comment: Yes, my old projects were working quite fine in 32 bits.

Comment: May be within your project you need to check which Java compiler it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue like yours. I run eclipse as administrator and the error disappeared 
so it seems that I didn't have enough privileges on my java folder.